# How to find the area of the image under T?

Tags: linear-algebra

For this question, I'm not sure how to continue further. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Let $T:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ be the linear transformation defined by $T([x,y]) = [4x-2y, 2x+3y]$. Find the area of the image under T of each of the given regions in $\Bbb R^2$.

The parallelogram determined by $2e_1 + 3e_2$ and $4e_1-e_2$.

$A = [4,-2],[2,3]$

$A^T = [4,2],[-2,3]$

$ A^T*A = [20,-2],[-2,13]$

$det([20,-2],[-2,13]) = 256$

$V = \sqrt{256} = 16$

Comment: What is $A^T $ needed for? If you start with $v_1,v_2$, you can find $Tv_1,Tv_2$ and then the area enclosed by these two vectors (using abs val of det of a matrix that contains  these two vectors).

Comment: Isn't the transpose part of the formula to calculate the area or volume?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The area of a region under a linear map $T$ is scaled by $|\det(T)|$. Your problem boils down to finding the area of the original parallelogram and then multiplying it by the absolute value of the determinant you found.

Comment: To find the area of the original parallelogram do we just subtract the e1 and e2 values? I get a negative number when I do that

Comment: No? Why would that give you the area? You can take the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix with the two vectors as colums

Comment: $T(2e_1+3e_2) = 2T(e_1)+3T(e_2)$ and $T(4e_1-e_2) = 4T(e_1)-T(e_2)$ Do I just plug in the matrix into the two equations? What do I do afterwards?

Comment: How do we calculate the area of the original parallelogram when the values are e?

Comment: If you would like to do it that way, that's fine, you can calculate the area of the parallelogram given by the vectors $T(2e_1+3e_2)$ and $T(4e_1-e_2)$, which yes, you find by using the rule defining $T$. Again, you will need to know how to find the volume of a parallelogram spanned by two vectors; as I said, this is done by computing the determinant of the matrix

Comment: I got the determinant but I'm not sure how to get the area of the parallelogram. Do we add the two transformations and then multiply by the determinant to get the area of the whole thing?

Comment: @dg123 please see here: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~daddel/linear_algebra_appl/Applications/Determinant/Determinant/node4.html